# Angular8+ renders element in template twice

Tags: angular

In our projekt we get always after shift + f5 reload an element rendered twice. If we navigate away and come back it is rendered once. The problem occurs in chrome and in firefox and in current version.

Here we se the form element doubled:
[image]
Here it look correctly:
[image]

Complete template i just removed the grid column definition:

```html
<div *ngIf="!applicationService.isEmbedded" fxLayout="column" fxFill>
    <h1 class="page-title">{{ "messages.chronology.title" | translate }}</h1>
    <mat-card fxFlex="grow">
        <mat-card-content *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="applicationService.isEmbedded">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #content>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="15px" fxFill>
        <!-- somehow if ngif is directly on form it gets rendered double -->
        <div *ngIf="!applicationService.isEmbedded">
            <form fxFlex #ngForm>
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="5px">
                    <mat-label fxFlex="12">{{ "messages.chronology.liuid-search-label" | translate }}*</mat-label>
                    <pam-simple-liuid-selector fxFlex [hideLabel]="true" [singleSelect]="true" (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"></pam-simple-liuid-selector>
                </div>
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="5px">
                    <mat-label fxFlex="12">{{ "messages.chronology.time-range-label" | translate }}*</mat-label>
                    <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
                        <dx-date-box [(ngModel)]="startDate" type="datetime" name="startDate" placeholder="Start date" width="100%" #startDateInput="ngModel"></dx-date-box>
                        <dx-date-box [(ngModel)]="endDate" type="datetime" name="endDate" placeholder="End date" width="100%" #endDateInput="ngModel"></dx-date-box>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div fxFlex="grow" style="position: relative">
            <dx-data-grid>
<!-- dxGrid Column definition removed because it's not needed to solve that problem -->
            </dx-data-grid>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: this is a template definition, need to see where it's used

Comment: Why are you loading AngularJs?

Comment: Added the complete Template just without grid column definition. AngularJs was added by stackoverflow code editor. There it was only possible to set AngularJs not Angular8+